# How to chain solr request by keyboard type?

Tags: solr

Solr is used as search engine for a third party system. Sometimes clients type their requests with wrong keyboard layout, for example russian word 'привет' (hi) is typed like 'ghbdtn'. I'm searching for possible SOLR avaibility to transform this into correct keyboard layout.

I'v tried several filters, such as SnowballPorterFilterFactory and SynonymFilterFactory but it's hard to fill synonims for all cases

Is it possible to tune SOLR for this task or should I perfrom converison into other system?

I will be grateful for any suggestions. If I request could be fixed in java - please provide appropriate liblary

Answer (score 1):

You can [add a MappingCharFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.MappingCharFilterFactory) to your processing chain. Add a new field type with the MappingCharFilter as the first step, then use a `copyField` instruction to get the same data into the new field as well.

The mapping file would then be a set of character mappings between the two keyboard layouts:

```
"п" => "g"
"р" => "h"
"и" => "b"
```

.. etc.

You can then also score the new field lower than the correct field by using `qf` with weights in your edismax query.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment. I would like to use it as workaround, cause it might be additional pressue for index.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found another solution, probably it is not connected to SOLR itself.

If SOLR returns nothing for wrong request, I'll do another one where change letters from Russian to English. This is handled by third party system during request creation.

If you have more easy approach or any comments - please post it.